# How to deal with frequent application changes from GUI automation perspective through Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, ui-automation

I am currently testing an enterprise application using Selenium which has lots of Legacy pages. Hence management has decided to revamp the entire application GUI and workflow through phase wise implementation of the changes. As we have automated handful of tests , it has started failing as the application workflow and GUI is changing. How can i deal with it? Should i update my tests. If yes there are chances that the same feature may further be refined or tweaked in near future.

Should I wait for the entire functionality changes to be frozen which i think is not a good option .

How can I make sure my automation suite is adding value for the application frequent delivery? How and when should I accommodate those changes?

Comment: Best way to handle is use "id" or "name". if not better use customize relative xpaths. if you are using xpath its better to use less paths withing relative xpath. That can be minimize your changes. 
Also use page factory or page object model. so you need to change elements within one place rather than change in everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question one by one:

- *It has started failing as the application workflow and GUI is changing. How can i deal with it?* While performing *Test Automation* using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), there is no bulletproof solution to changing GUI as the attributes of the *WebElements* and the optimum [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) would also change accordingly. However *logical locators* may provide some relief.
- *Should I update my tests?* If the *GUI* nd the workflow is changing there is no second option other then to update your tests.
- *There are chances that the same feature may further be refined or tweaked in near future*: Ideally *Test Automation* should be conducted on stable functionalities with **zero** regression defects as a result of new code submissions or code changes.

> **Conclusion**: Wait for the entire functionality changes to be frozen. Follow the *Test Strategy* as per the *Test Specification*.